# Using Yup and Formik, how to get index number when validating conditional property inside of fields array?

Tags: reactjs, validation, conditional-statements, formik, yup

I need to show and validate "hourlyCommitment" field ONLY when "commitment" field has a value of "3". The problem is, I can't seem to access the "current index" of the array field, so the validation doesn't work. Any ideas would be appreciated

```
professionals: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
        talent: Yup.number().required(translates.FormsErrorsRequired),
        seniority: Yup.number().required(translates.FormsErrorsRequired),
        commitment: Yup.number().required(translates.FormsErrorsRequired),
        hourlyCommitment: Yup.number()
            .nullable()
            .when('professionals[currentIndex].commitment', {
                is: '3',
                then: Yup.number().required(translates.FormsErrorsRequired),
            }),
        quantity: Yup.number().required(translates.FormsErrorsRequired),
        skills: Yup.array().of(
            Yup.object().shape({
                value: Yup.string(),
                label: Yup.string(),
            })
        ),
    })
),
```

Seems I solved it:

```
professionals: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
        talent: Yup.number().required(translates.FormsErrorsRequired),
        seniority: Yup.number().required(translates.FormsErrorsRequired),
        commitment: Yup.number().required(translates.FormsErrorsRequired),
        hourlyCommitment: Yup.number().test({
            name: 'hourlyCommitment',
            exclusive: true,
            message: translates.FormsErrorsRequired,
            test: (value, context) => {
                return !!value || context.parent.commitment !== 3;
            },
        }),
        quantity: Yup.number().required(translates.FormsErrorsRequired),
        skills: Yup.array().of(
            Yup.object().shape({
                value: Yup.string(),
                label: Yup.string(),
            })
        ),
    })
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use commitment in initial values?
Are they different values with professionals[current].commitment?
If yes, then define a variable called currentCommitment and set it to professionals[current].commitment, then use it in validation